# SSIS 2014 Lookup Transformation with SQL Server Destination

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to implement a Lookup Transformation in SSIS 2014 to load "no match output" into "SQL Server Destination", but I got errors at runtime:

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Test dataflow" (58) failed with error code 0xC02020C7 while processing input "SQL Server Destination Input" (74). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

As source task the "OLE DB Source" is used.

The Lookup Transformation uses the no cache mode.

In "SQL Server Destination"-Task: "Table lock" and "Check constraints" are checked and the timeout is set to 30.

What am I doing wrong? Could please someone help to solve this error?

Comment: `There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge you cannot use SQL Server Destination while loading data, coming from Lookup Transformation.
You need to use OLE DB Destination.